# Jenkins node android device

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration

i have own little server, some usb hub, and 6 android devices as samsung galaxy s3. Please tell  how i can attach device to each nodes. I have plugin for Jenkins "External resource dispatchers". And just want connect these device, to start automation testing.

Jenkins version - 1.517

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Plug in the devices via usb and take note of all the unique serial numbers that `adb devices -l` reports. Your build scripts will have to be sensitive to this serial number for it to work.

Then, you can create one node in Jenkins with the "Dumb node" type and pick the "Launch slave agents on Unix machines via SSH" method (ssh to localhost).

Under "node properties" -> "environment variables" add a variable named ANDROID_DEVICE_ID with the value of one of the serial numbers. Repeat for each unique android serial.

In the end, you will have *n* jenkins nodes, each setting its own ANDROID_DEVICE_ID value.

An alternative would be to create a parameterized build that takes an android serial as a parameter and make your build scripts sensitive to it.